# CircuitLab DC parameter sweep problem circuit

Tags: simulation, debugging, circuitlab

The following circuit, taken from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/588268/268467) seems to give odd results when doing a parameter sweep simulation on CircuitLab. Is the problem with CircuitLab, or is there some problem with the circuit that I do not see.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUO8D4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The intent of the circuit is to provide a constant current through R3 so that its value may be determined by measuring the voltage across it. When I ran a sweep which varied the value of R3 from 10 to 200 \$\Omega\$, a "notch" in the output voltage appears.
[image]
However, the \$V_{be}\$s and \$I_b\$s of the transistors look fine.

[image]
[image]

Changing the transistors to BC327's gives an even more erratic sweep.

[image]

Removing either the ammeter or the voltmeter from the circuit makes the problem go away!

Also of interest, if the value of R3 is manually set between 140 and 166 \$\Omega\$, DC simulation gives the correct answer. The problem only seems to occur with DC sweep.

Does anyone know the cause of this, or the precise conditions under which it occurs?

---

Update: Checked on 19 April 2022, and problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for examining this. I verified your findings (after your comment to my answer in the linked question) but found that the meters read correctly when R3 was set at 150 and 160 ohms. I didn't try taking the meters out though so that's an interesting find.

Comment: Tip: SE supports HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, `&pm;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments). You don't need to use MathJAX just for a symbol.

Comment: LTspice doesn't seem to have this problem. But it also doesn't have an ammeter. So, there, one simply uses a 0 V voltage source to get the equivalent device. I'm guessing that CircuitLab is more focused on being a circuit-sharing site and less focused on being a quality simulator.

Comment: [LTspice gives this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNPO3.png).

Answer (score 2):

DC sweep tries to save time and reuse results from the previous step as a "seed". Turns out this seed makes convergence worse sometimes. I've ran into this bug many times.

The problems are twofold:

1. Loss of output voltage.
2. Loss of collector current on Q1.

[image: Output voltage plot with a chunk miscalculated]
[image: Collector currents, with a chunk of Q1's current miscalculated]

Workarounds:

1. For the loss of output voltage: set shunt resistance of AM1 non-zero. 1u ohm is fine.
2. Add a dummy parallel resistor to Q1, and switch it out of the circuit. The switch is optional for purists that worry about 1G ohm loading up the poor transistor :)

Yes, these problems are independent: fixing #1 still leaves #2 unfixed. It's a Schrodinger's transistor: if you observe the collector current, it goes into a superposition of working and non-working state, depending on which observer you ask. The pun potential mitigates some of the annoyance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6zRgI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It works with those workarounds:

[image: Output voltage plot=]
[image: Collector currents]

It also works when transistors are changed to BC327 :)